# Understanding NFA (nondeterministic finite automaton) with a null transition

Tags: automata, finite-automata

[image]

I'm reading [Computer Science: An Interdisciplinary Approach](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/). It mentioned an NFA (nondeterministic finite automaton) with a null transition, as shown above, recognizes all binary strings that do not contain `bba` as a substring.

I didn't quite understand why it says so. If the null transition happens before reading the `bba`, it stuck at state 2 and will report yes at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a run of an automaton reaches a state where it has no legal transitions for the next input character, that run rejects immediately.

So, in your example, if the automaton makes the null transition, it can read $bb$ while staying in state $2$.  But when it reads the $a$, it has no legal transition so that run rejects.  Any run that stays in states $0$ and $1$ must also reject, because those two states are rejecting states. Therefore, the automaton does indeed reject all strings containing $bba$.

Comment: Thanks @david-recherby

"If a run of an automaton reaches a state where it has no legal transitions for the next input character, that run rejects"

So it can reject the whole input without needing to reach the end, right?

Comment: That's correct. (I added the word "immediately" to the answer to suggest this more strongly.)

Comment: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/computer-science-an/9780134076461/graphics/0747fig01.jpg

In the above example, the author says it will accept `ababb` because we can establish the sequence of state transitions as 0-0-1-0-2-2-2.

But this is not deterministic, it is only one possible result, right?

Comment: Right. The automaton is nondeterministic, so it accepts as long as there is one or more accepting run.